# Which channel processes are allowed in the interaction $e^-+e^+\rightarrow 2\gamma$

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

s-, t- or u-channel? How can you tell?

Answer (score 1):

Since every vertex must be a electron-positron-photon vertex, and we are starting with an electron and positron, we must have a $t$ and a $u$ channel. Both must be possible because nothing about QED tells lets you distinguish which photon is which at the end of the process.

An $s$ channel diagram would require that you start with a photon and an electron to get a photon and a positron, i.e. $e^-\gamma\longrightarrow e^+\gamma$. Alternatively, there could be an $s$ channel if there were a photon-photon-photon vertex, which there is not.

To elaborate a bit, let's consider the QED Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac14F^2 + \overline{\psi}(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - m)\psi + q A_\mu(\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi)
$$
The last term here is multiplied by a charge $q$ and contains a photon $A_\mu$ and a positron and electron. This gives us a Feynman rule and an allowed vertex: the photon-positron-electron vertex with charge $q$. In fact, ignoring spinor indices, it tells us to multiply each vertex we encounter by $ie\gamma^\mu$.

Note that this is the *only* three vertex in the theory: there is no term involving $\partial_\mu A^\mu A^2$ for example, that might lead to a photon three vertex.

Since it's the only three vertex in the theory, all diagrams we build must be made up of these vertices. So, now we want to consider the problem at hand: $e^-e^+\longrightarrow 2\gamma$, meaning we start with an electron/positron and end with two photons.

Now you label each incoming particle with, say, $p_1$ for the electron and $p_2$ for the positron. You then label the outgoing photons, $p_3$ and $p_4$. Knowing that momentum is conserved at the vertex, you know that $p_1 + p_2 = p_3 + p_4$ - this will be enforced by a delta function in your final amplitude. And now you draw your diagram: you know that it can only consist of electron-positron-photon vertices and you will soon find that the only *internal* line you can have must be a fermion, so you draw the only diagram you can

[image]

However, you don't know which photon comes from which vertex: all you can measure are two photons with some momenta. So, you have to consider the possibility that the came from both vertices, so you consider the identical diagram but this time swapping the photon momenta. This, in effect, switches the $u$ and $t$ channels.

[image]

Comment: Our professor has only mentioned charge and flavour conservation when it comes to binary processes in QED, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I've added some extra stuff, although conservation at the vertex doesn't change the arguments much.

Comment: There is no problem with the s-channel existing, it's just that the photon is necessarily off-shell meaning that it is not an out-going line. This is the mechanism of Drell-Yan, after all.

Comment: The s channel can exist, it just can't result in two on-shell photons, since that requires a photon-photon-photon vertex.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your answer, this really helped!